# Just trying to access a value in an a element

Tags: javascript

I've got multiple `a elements`, that are generated on the page view by a for loop that when they are clicked, send an `ajax post` to the database, to mark the item in the database by its id, that is equal to the value in the `a element` but my code is not working, anybody have any insight on why? Thanks.

```
<a href='#' value='(loaded from database)' id='markAsRead'>

var element = document.getElementById('markAsRead');

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors don't have values like inputs do, you should use a data-attribute

```
<a href='#' data-value='(loaded from database)' id='markAsRead'>

var element = document.getElementById('markAsRead');

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
 alert(this.getAttribute("data-value"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and this is specific to the one a element right? Cause the loop loads many `id='markAsRead'`

Comment: @XCritics - the id attribute must be unique, if you want something like that you should use name or class (possibly something else too)

Answer (score 0):

the `id` attribute *must* be unique.

if you want to have a group of controls with the same identifier you can use the `name` attribite.

if you look at the functions for dom manipulation:

- `document.getElementById()` - Element (singular)
- `document.getElementsByName()` - Elements (plural)

An example of adding a unique (depending on circumstances) id

```
for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("data-value", "your value");
    element.setAttribute("id", "markAsRead_" + index);
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.getAttribute("data-value"));
    });
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: You were missing a comma in your `addEventListener` try http://jsfiddle.net/Du5LY/10/